# Intersection and probability

Tags: probability

From Wasserman's *All of Statistics*...

Suppose $\mathbb{P}(A_j) = 1 $ for all $j$.  Prove that
$$\mathbb{P}\left( \bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty  A_i\right) = 1$$

This is easy to prove of the events are independent , but that is not explicitly said.

EDIT: There is a result further down that asks me to prove that if $P(A) = 1$ then $A$ is independent of every other event.

Well, I know that if $X \subset Y$ then $P(X) \leq P(Y)$,so

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cup B)$$
$$ = 1 + P(B) - 1 $$
$$=P(B)$$

Therefore $A$ is independent of all other events.

I can apply this result to my problem, which easily solves it.

$$\mathbb{P}\left( \bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty  A_i\right) = \prod_{i = 1}^n P(A_j) =  1$$

Comment: Can you show the complement has probability $0$?

Comment: Is measure theory permissible?

Comment: @joeb you know what, yea why not.  I am interested to see how you would do that.

Comment: Isn't that how probability is defined in the first place @joeb?

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathbb{P}\left( \bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty  A_i\right) = 1 \iff \mathbb{P}\Biggl(\,\overline{\bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty  A_i}\,\Biggr) =\mathbb{P}\left({\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty  \overline{A_i}}\right) = 0.
$$

Look at Exercise 7 to the first Chapter of Wasserman's All of Statistics... It ask to prove (supplied with good hint) that for any $A_i$
$$\mathbb{P}\left({\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i}\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb P(A_i).$$

Apply this inequality with $\overline{A_i}$. Since $\mathbb P\bigl(\overline{A_i}\bigr) = 1-\mathbb P(A_i)=1-1=0$ for any $i$,
$$\mathbb{P}\left({\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty \overline{A_i}}\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb P\bigl(\overline{A_i}\bigr)=0$$
which concludes the proof.

Concerning your proof. You can only conclude that any event $A_i$ is independent on any other event. We can take $A_j$ ($j\neq i$) or $A_j\cap A_m$ ($j\neq i$, $m\neq i$) or smth more complicated for this second event.

This fact allows one to conclude step-by-step at most that 
$$\mathbb{P}\left( \bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty  A_i\right) = \mathbb{P}(A_1)\times\mathbb{P}\left( \bigcap_{i = 2}^\infty  A_i\right) =\mathbb{P}(A_1)\times\mathbb{P}(A_2)\times\mathbb{P}\left( \bigcap_{i = 3}^\infty  A_i\right)=\ldots = $$
$$=\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(A_i)\times\mathbb{P}\left( \bigcap_{i = n+1}^\infty  A_i\right)
$$
but any step we have a **finite** product with the last factor as unknown as the original probability. To prove that 
$$\mathbb{P}\left( \bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty  A_i\right) =\prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(A_i)$$ you should solve the original problem: to prove that if $\mathbb P(A_i)=1$ for any $i$, then
$$\mathbb{P}\left( \bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty  A_i\right) = \prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(A_i) = 1.$$

Definitely, you can do it. Say, look at [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/942074/413376) using continuity of probabilities (Theorem 2.8 in the Book).

But if we already solve the original problem, there is no need in independence.

Comment: I did manage to prove problem 7, thanks that makes things very easy.  I'm not sure I understand your criticism of my attempt though.  Where exactly is the fault in my logic?

Comment: @DemetriP Nothing fault, but the last conclusion if not proved: $$\require{cancel}\mathbb{P}\left( \bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty  A_i\right)  = \prod_{i=1}^{\color{red}{\cancel{\text{$\color{black}n$}}}\infty} \mathbb P(A_j).$$ 
The independence of each of the evens $A_i$ from any other event does not imply this conclusion in a short way. It cannot be proved this way without continuity of measure.